# How to refactor in partials or make more dry the code of a Haml file which contains tabs with common structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, haml

I'm developing in a Ruby on Rails 4.2.10 project and I was asked to refactor a panel which contains tabs in a better way dividing into partials, all build in `Haml`. I did that but still, they said I need to do it better especially with this file:

```
.dashboard_tabs
  .dashboard_tab.active{ data: { tab: 'problems' } }
    - shipments_count = problem_shipments.try(:count) || 0
    %h2 Problems
    .badge.danger{ class: [shipments_count.zero? && 'empty'] }= shipments_count

  .dashboard_tab{ data: { tab: 'created' } }
    - shipments_count = shipments.try(:count) || 0
    %h2 Created
    .badge{ class: [shipments_count.zero? && 'empty'] }= shipments_count

  .dashboard_tab{ data: { tab: 'requests' } }
    - shipments_count = shipment_requests.try(:count) || 0
    %h2 RFQ
    .badge{ class: [shipments_count.zero? && 'empty'] }= shipments_count

  .dashboard_tab{ data: { tab: 'pickups' } }
    - shipments_count = pickups.try(:count) || 0
    %h2 Pickup request
    .badge{ class: [shipments_count.zero? && 'empty'] }= shipments_count
```

The comment was "These tabs seem to have a lot in common to be extracted" so I don't know how to make it drier as I've been asked.

Hope to get some good suggestions fr it.

Other files related to this are the next:

Index

```
= react_component("CompanyDashboard", Jbuilder.new { |json| json.initialDashboard @view_model.to_builder; json.initialCarrierOptions @carrier_list.to_builder; json.initialCustomerOptions @customer_list.to_builder; json.remoteDashboardDataURL companies_dashboard_data_path(format: "json"); json.remoteCarrierAutocompleteURL companies_autocomplete_carriers_path(format: "json"); json.remoteCustomerAutocompleteURL companies_autocomplete_customers_path(format: "json") }.target!)

#dashboard_chart_container
  .chart_labels
  .loading_indicator{ :style => "display: none" }
    .loading_indicator_wrapper
      = image_tag("admin/loading_indicator.gif")
  %svg{ :id => "dashboard_chart", :width => "100%", :height => "300" }

.dashboard_separator

- problem_shipments = @view_model.problem_shipments
- shipments         = @view_model.created_shipments
- shipment_requests = @view_model.rfq_shipments
- pickups           = @view_model.pickup_requests

= render(partial: 'shipment_tabs', locals: { problem_shipments: @view_model.problem_shipments, shipments: shipments, shipment_requests: shipment_requests, pickups: pickups })

/ Problems tab
.dashboard_panel{ data: { tab: 'problems'} }
  .dashboard_panel_body
    - if problem_shipments.try(:any?)
      %table
        %tbody
          = render(partial: "shipment_row_for_panel", collection: problem_shipments.limit(100), as: :shipment)
    - else
      .empty No problems at the moment

/ Created tab
.dashboard_panel.hidden{ data: { tab: 'created'} }
  .dashboard_panel_body
    - if shipments.any?
      %table
        %tbody
          = render(partial: "shipment_row_for_panel", collection: shipments.limit(100), as: :shipment)
    - else
      .empty No requests at the moment

/ RFQ tab
.dashboard_panel.hidden{ data: { tab: 'requests'} }
  .dashboard_panel_body
    - if shipment_requests.any?
      %table
        %tbody
          = render(partial: "shipment_request_row_for_panel", collection: shipment_requests.limit(100), as: :shipment_request)
    - else
      .empty No requests at the moment

/ Pickup request tab
.dashboard_panel.hidden{ data: { tab: 'pickups'} }
  .dashboard_panel_body
    - if pickups.any?
      %table
        %tbody
          = render(partial: "pickup_row_for_panel", collection: pickups.limit(100), as: :pickup)
    - else
      .empty No requests at the moment
```

shipment partial

```
%tr
  %td
    = shipment.customer_name_for_company(company_id: current_company.id)
  %td.id
    = link_to(shipment.unique_shipment_id, companies_shipment_path(shipment))
  %td.date
    = shipment.shipping_date
  %td
    = shipment.carrier_product.suffixed_name
  %td
    = render("components/shared/contact", contact: shipment.sender)
  %td
    = render("components/shared/contact", contact: shipment.recipient)
  %td.awb
    = render(partial: "components/shared/carrier_products/awb", locals: { shipment: shipment })

- if shipment.description.present?
  %tr.description
    %td{ :colspan => "7" }= shipment.description
```

Partial pickup

```
%tr
  %td
    = pickup.customer_name
  %td.id
    = link_to(pickup.unique_pickup_id, companies_pickup_path(pickup))
  %td.date
    = pickup.pickup_date
  %td
    = pickup.from_time
  %td
    = pickup.to_time
  %td
    = pickup.description
```

Partial shipment request

```
%tr
  %td
    = link_to(shipment_request.shipment.unique_shipment_id, companies_shipment_request_path(shipment_request))
  %td
    = shipment_request.shipment.shipping_date
  %td
    = "#{shipment_request.shipment.sender.company_name},"
    %br/
    = shipment_request.shipment.sender.country_name
  %td
    = "#{shipment_request.shipment.recipient.company_name},"
    %br/
    = shipment_request.shipment.recipient.country_name
  %td
    = suffixed_name(name: shipment_request.shipment.carrier_product.name, company: shipment_request.shipment.company)

- if shipment_request.shipment.description.present?
  %tr.description
    %td{ :colspan => "5" }= shipment_request.shipment.description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a partial `_dashboard_tab` as follows

```
.dashboard_tab{class: active ? 'active' : '', data: {tab: tab_name}
  - shipments_count = shipments.try(:count) || 0
  %h2= title 
  .badge{ class: [shipments_count.zero? && 'empty'] }= shipments_count
```

you can then rewrite the original view as follows:

```
.dashboard_tabs
  = render 'dashboard_tab', active: true, tab_name: 'problems', |
                            title: 'Problems', shipments: problem_shipments
  = render 'dashboard_tab', active: false, tab_name: 'created', | 
                            title: 'Created', shipments: shipments
  = render 'dashboard_tab', active: false, tab_name: 'requests', |
                            title: 'RFQ', shipments: shipment_requests
  = render 'dashboard_tab', active: false, tab_name: 'requests', |
                            title: 'RFQ', shipments: shipment_requests
  = render 'dashboard_tab', active: false, tab_name: 'pickups', |
                            title: 'Pickup request', shipments: pickups
```

This is a start. We now miss the `danger` class for the problems badge, and we repeat the `active` while we only want to first to be active (and the default is false).

So we can optimise our partial a little more by adding an extra badge-class (and make it optional) and making the active state also optional.

So we adapt the partial as follows:

```
 - active = local_assigns.has_key?(:active) ? active : false 
 - badge_class = local_assigns.has_key?(:badge_class) ? badge_class : ''
 .dashboard_tab{class: active ? 'active' : '', data: {tab: tab_name}
   - shipments_count = shipments.try(:count) || 0
   %h2= title 
   - badge_classes = [badge_class] 
   - badge_classes << 'empty' if shipments_count.zero?
   .badge{ class: badge_classes.join(" ") }= shipments_count
```

and then we can write the original tab-list as follows:

```
.dashboard_tabs
  = render 'dashboard_tab', active: true, badge_class: 'danger', tab_name: 'problems', |
                            title: 'Problems', shipments: problem_shipments
  = render 'dashboard_tab', tab_name: 'created',  title: 'Created', shipments: shipments,
  = render 'dashboard_tab', tab_name: 'requests', title: 'RFQ', shipments: shipment_requests
  = render 'dashboard_tab', tab_name: 'requests', title: 'RFQ', shipments: shipment_requests
  = render 'dashboard_tab', tab_name: 'pickups',  title: 'Pickup request', shipments: pickups
```

Comment: Good just to understand. The first of the above last 2 codes lines. The first is what I should define in my partials and the second I will put in my index? 
Could you add the changes in my files so I can understand where I should do the change? I understood the first is for the partial and the second for the index is that correct?

Comment: `shipments.try(:count)` will create a N+1 query issue as `count` issues a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` query. You should instead use `.size` as it will use `.length` if the collection is already loaded or the counter cache. You can also use `any?` or `none?` that defer to `.size`.

Comment: Also using `.try` might not be needed either as you are dealing with an empty collection and not nil values (hopefully).

Comment: Hi @jakub you understood correctly (not sure how you could understand it otherwise?)

Comment: Ok but on the first partial I get errors inline the code from editor as saying is not Haml formatted or else related to that

Comment: Hi @jakub this code is untested obviously. I am just giving a start-point.

Comment: I'm unable to make it work unfortunately I never used Haml so cannot understand how should be changed :(

Comment: Indentation is important, and that is probably what is causing the problem. Can you post your partial (or the view that is giving the error) and the error?

Comment: Ow is it the index? Because in haml if a line is split over two lines, you have to add a `|` (pipe) add the end (I just formatted the code to be readable here --just place it on one line or add the `|` at the end). See reference: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#multiline

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really experienced in HAML, but I think that what they meant by "These tabs seem to have a lot in common to be extracted" is that your are more or less writing the same code for different variables.

What you could do, is pass a unique array variable to your tabs partial, for instance:

```
render(partial: 'shipment_tabs', 
  locals: { data: [
    { name: "Problems", tab: "problems", count: @view_model.problem_shipments.try(:count) || 0 },
    { name: "Created", tab: "created", count: shipments.try(:count) || 0 },
    { name: "RFQ", tab: "requests", count: shipment_requests.try(:count) || 0 },
    { name: "Pickup request", tab: "pickups", count: pickups.try(:count) || 0 }
  ] }
)
```

And in your partial just loop on this array

```
.dashboard_tabs
  - data.each do |entry|
    .dashboard_tab.active{ data: { tab: entry["tab"] } }
      %h2 #{entry["name"]}
      .badge.danger{ class: [entry["count"].zero? && 'empty'] }= entry["count"]
```

Comment: Ok make sense but the first suggestion I have to make a new partial for it or I will change the file I shared first into that? 
Like both your suggestions will be added to the same file?

Comment: The first suggestion is just and edit from the partial call in your `Index` at line 17, I've abstracted the reste of the code

Comment: Ok on this line 
.badge.danger{ class: [entry["count"].zero? && 'empty'] }= entry["count"] 
I get error now 
undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass